# Google Earth type, online plate-techtonics demonstration over time

Tags: geology, plate-tectonics

I once found an site on the internet that displayed the continents in a Google Earth type setting where you could spin, zoom and navigate around the Earth but in different geological time periods. You were essentially able to slide a time bar across and see the different continental configurations of a certain place over time. If someone is aware of this site please would you let me know. I've searched to no avail.

Comment: There used to be a number of such animations -- including one at my institution -- that were created using Adobe Flash. The Flash player wound up being so resource-intensive, especially in mobile environments, that browsers progressively blocked it and Adobe ended support for Flash in 2021.